# Delete multilple marked items

Tags: php, mysql, html

How can I delete multiple items from a list displayed in html.

For example

```
<ul>
 <li>item 1</li>checkbox
 <li>item 2</li>
</ul>

<a href="delete.php?ids=checkedids">Delete items</a>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easy way to do this in PHP is to *give all your check boxes the same name, and have that name end with `[]`*:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="3" />
```

Then your script gets all the checked values as an array:

```
if(empty($_REQUEST['item'])) {
    // No items checked
}
else {
    foreach($_REQUEST['item'] as $id) {
        // delete the item with the id $id
    }
}
```

To make this work, you need to put the check boxes into a `<form>`, and use a submit button (not a link -- that will not work, unless you start using JavaScript) like this:

```
<form method="post" target="some/php/script.php">
    <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item[]" value="3" />
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete checked items" />
</form>
```

There are some possible improvements to this (see Crozin's answer), but you should get the basics down first.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you should use a form. You can use checkboxes to select items to delete and then use following query:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_name WHERE id_col_name IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
```

HTML form itself could look like following:

```
<form ...>
    ...
    <li>
        <label>Delete item #123 <input type="checkbox" name="delete[123]" />
    </li>
    ...
</form>
```

Then list of IDs is easily available under `$_POST['delete']` array.

Comment: what would you do if there were multiple columns for where.